# Pausing in Java

Tags: java

So I'm a beginning programmer and I'm trying to make a pong game(but horizontal). There is only one slight problem. After the user has scored a point the ball will immediatly return to the player. I would like to know if there's a way to start a little delay to give the player some time to react. Here is the 'scoring' system I'm using.

Thank you in advance!

```
 if(yBall<=100-barHeight*0.5){

    yBall = 300;
    xBall = 400;
    text_player2 = text_player2+1;
    yBallSpeed = yBallSpeed *-1;
    xBar = width*0.5 - barWidth*0.5;

    //pause for few seconds 

    }
```

Comment: try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(InterruptedException ex){}

Comment: You can use Thread.sleep(1000); it will wait 1000ms (1 second).

Comment: this is a duplicate of at least a dozen like questions, stupid duplicate panel selected the wrong one when I closed it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Thread.sleep(millisecs)`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Note, that you "have to put" `Thread.sleep(millisecs)` in a try-catch block (or add throw to the method):

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

Comment: No, you don't have to put it in a try/catch block. You can, for instance, declare that the containing method `throws InterruptedException`. And if you do catch it, you probably want to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, otherwise you lose the fact that the thread was interrupted.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, that's right, but for this simple use case I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can make the currently executing Thread go to sleep for x milliseconds using

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

If this is a beginner programming excercise then this might do for you. Make sure you catch the exception that this method throws.

Also please think about if you really want to sleep the thread the game runs on. Maybe you want to keep processing user input (e.g. if he wants to quit) but schedule the new ball bit later. For that, you can check out what [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is for

Comment: Make sure you *handle* the exception that this method throws. Don't just catch it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're doing this in a per-frame operation of your game, so `Thread.sleep` would be bad practice. Instead of pausing the game, it will make the game hang unresponsively for a certain time period (this may or may not be ok for yours).

Consider using `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead, which returns the current time in milliseconds:

```
long deadLine = 0L;

// Your method for updating the game's state
void updateState() {
    if (deadline > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        // The game is currently paused. Draw a "Get Ready" string maybe?
        return;
    }

    if (gameShouldRestart()) {
        // The game should not do anything for the next two seconds:
        deadLine = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000L;

        // Reset game state here.
    }
}
```

Now the `updateState()` method will return immediately and let the game keep rendering but without doing anything, instead of just lagging the game for several seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to invoke an action after a delay without causing the current thread to block. Try to reuse the same `ScheduledExecutorService` across your whole application, and make sure you shut it down at the end.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
try {
    executor.schedule(() -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        readyToRestart(); // your method that restarts the action
    }), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} finally { executor.shutdown(); }
```

Since the `ScheduledExecutorService` will run the scheduled action on its own thread, you will need to make sure the action does not cause any threading related problems. How you do this depends on what GUI toolkit you are using. In the example I show how to do it in Swing using the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` method.